# How to give execute permission for External Data Source in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, privileges

I have created external source data in SQL Server. I can able to run the following query in admin user.,

```
EXEC sp_execute_remote
N'ExternalSource',
N'SELECT Top 2 * FROM [dbo].[MyUsers]'
GO
```

But I am getting following error, if run the same query in another user login

> User does not have permission to perform this action.

Could you please any help on this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: ["Requires `ALTER ANY EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE` permission."](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-remote-azure-sql-database#permissions). If that's not acceptable (as I imagine it might not be) you can encapsulate the functionality in a stored procedure with `EXECUTE AS`.

Comment: We are using SQL Server Azure Database